# Checkboxes causing email submission to goto 404

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created a form (I've left parts out) that collects the user's checkbox selections (which are created via Wordpress) and emails the results back to me.

When I tick the hardware selections and submit the email comes through fine but when I tick any of the accessories and click submit it goes to a 404 page.

Can anyone see where the error is? I've created the two sets of checkboxes and results in the same way, just can't see where the error is!

```
<form id="customisesystem" name="enquiry" method="POST" onSubmit="return formCheck(this);" action="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>">
  <div id="customise-area">
    <?php $posts = get_field('options');
                            if( $posts ):
                            $items = 0;
                            foreach( $posts as $post): // variable must be called $post (IMPORTANT)
                                setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <div class="custom-option">
      <p><b>
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        </b></p>
      <br />
      <div>
        <p><?php echo the_field('description'); ?></p>
      </div>
      <?php $counter = 1; while(the_repeater_field('images')): ?>
      <?php if($counter <= 1) { ?>
      <img width="180" height="136" src="<?php the_sub_field('image'); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
      <?php } ?>
      <?php $counter++; endwhile; ?>
      <p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="hardware[]" value="<?php the_title(); ?>">
        Select</p>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <?php $items++; endforeach;
                            wp_reset_postdata(); // IMPORTANT - reset the $post object so the rest of the page works correctly
                            endif; ?>
  </div>
  <div id="customise-area">
    <?php $posts = get_field('accessories');
                            if( $posts ):
                            $items = 0;
                            foreach( $posts as $post): // variable must be called $post (IMPORTANT)
                                setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <div class="custom-option">
      <p><b>
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        </b></p>
      <br />
      <div>
        <p><?php echo the_field('description'); ?></p>
      </div>
      <?php $counter = 1; while(the_repeater_field('images')): ?>
      <?php if($counter <= 1) { ?>
      <img width="180" height="136" src="<?php the_sub_field('image'); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
      <?php } ?>
      <?php $counter++; endwhile; ?>
      <p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="accessories[]" value="<?php the_title(); ?>">
        Select</p>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <?php $items++; endforeach;
                            wp_reset_postdata(); // IMPORTANT - reset the $post object so the rest of the page works correctly
                            endif; ?>
  </div>
  <? if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 

$to = "rob@domain.com";
$header = 'From: rob@domain.com';
$subject = "Domain: Quotation";
$enquiry_first_name = $_POST['enquiryfirstname'];
$enquiry_last_name = $_POST['enquirylastname'];
$enquiry_title = $_POST['enquirytitle'];
$enquiry_organisation = $_POST['enquiryorganisation'];
$enquiry_address = $_POST['enquiryaddress'];
$enquiry_country = $_POST['enquirycountry'];
$enquiry_email_address = $_POST['enquiryemailaddress'];
$enquiry_telephone = $_POST['enquirytelephone'];
$enquiry_additional_comments = $_POST['enquiryadditionalcomments'];
$enquiry_product = get_the_title();
if(!empty($_POST['hardware'])) {
    foreach($_POST['hardware'] as $check) {
        $hardwareresults .= $check."\n";
    }
}
if(!empty($_POST['accessories'])) {
    foreach($_POST['accessories'] as $test) {
        $accessoriesresults .= $test."\n";
    }
}

$body = "You have a quote request from the website:

Quotation:
$enquiry_product

Hardware:
$hardwareresults

Accessories:
$accessoriesresults

Name: $enquiry_title $enquiry_first_name $enquiry_last_name
Type of organisation: $enquiry_organisation 
Address: $enquiry_address, $enquiry_country
E-Mail: $enquiry_email_address 
Tel: $enquiry_telephone
Comments: $enquiry_additional_comments

Kind regards";

mail($to, $subject, $body, $header);

echo "Thank you for your enquiry.";

} ?>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having spent 2 days on this problem I've found the most frustrating answer! Where I had the checkbox value as `accessories[]`, I changed that to `access[]` and it worked.

I can't quite explain why but would it be the length of the value var?

Answer (score 1):

**To start** use `htmlspecialchars` in values output:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="accessories[]" value="<?php the_title(); ?>">
<input type="checkbox" name="accessories[]" value="<?php htmlspecialchars(the_title()); ?>">
```

**Second**: You `formCheck` twice,

> ```
> in <form id="customisesystem"> and `<input type="submit" />`.
> ```

Just left one.

**and Third and the most important.**

WP does not works as you seem to think. Following condition it should be checked inside a suitable `hook` as `init`:

```
add_action('init', 'check_form');
function check_form(){
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
        // check form
        if (is_OK)
            // redirect to same page
            wp_redirect($my_url);
        else
            // continue to show the form to allow modification
    }
}
```

---

**Fourth**: your page shows a message error due `expects parameter 1 to be string, array given` for php functions. So do this:

Go to lines 1452and 968 and make a debug of vars passed to those functions and show what they are:

> var_dump()

Probably you are doing something like this:

```
trim($_POST['accessories']);
```

but you should do something like this:

```
foreach ($_POST['accessories'] as $val)
{
    $new_val = $val;
    $new_val = trim($new_val);
    $new_val = strip_tags($new_val);

    // more ....
}
```

Comment: @rob ok mate you have a lot of changes to do, specially for the `Fourth` part

Comment: @NomikOS Thanks for working through it. Points 1 & 2 didn't effect anything so I think I can rule them out for the moment. Is point 3 relating to the checking on the form and submit? I've removed that for the checking to rule it out and it still does the same. Just point 4 to try - is that in the email submission part?

Comment: @NomikOS It seems strange that hardware checkboxes go through fine but as soon as I check an accessory it goes to the 404.

Comment: #rob yes, weird as all bugs until you look directly to their eyes. Just debug with `var_dump`. OK. have to go. good luck...

Answer (score 1):

I think, that hasn't directly to do anything with the above code (or the error will just be called as a constraint function call to an CMS internal function that affects this behavior), but I looked at the posted site and tried it out.

When everything is fine, the URL is the same as the 404 error (and both are output with a `200 OK` HTTP header. That's weird and seems like this is an issue with the whole system you are running it on. I've taken a look at the 404 page and found some PHP errors, that are output first:

> **Warning**:  trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array
>   given in
>   **/home/teamwork/public_html/clients/rogue/wp-includes/query.php**
>   on line **1452**
>  
>  **Warning**:  strip_tags() expects
>   parameter 1 to be string, array given in
>   **/home/teamwork/public_html/clients/rogue/wp-includes/formatting.php**
>   on line **968**

Perhaps these WordPress functions are called. Can you debug where/when they are called exactly?

Maybe that affects your CMS to go into an error mode instead of rendering the right view?

Comment: @nlsnshtr I thought the same, in all the sites I've done it's never gone to an error page yet have the correct URL!?

Comment: Ok I've removed the `setup_postdata($post;)` but still the same thing happens. I'm a bit reluctant to edit core wordpress files but really can't see why this shouldn't work considering it works for the hardware checkboxes.

Comment: That doesn't show because of my use of Jquery hide/show (something I need to sort out!), if you go back through the quote it's below the submit button!

Comment: I'm probably going to redirect to a new page as there's a lot of info to go on the thank you page.